# How use nextval in sequence using node-postgres

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

my table postgres database has an auto increment key.

In convencional postgres sql I can:

```
INSERT INTO CITY(ID,NAME) VALUES(nextval('city_sequence_name'),'my first city');
```

How can I do this using node-postgres ? Until now, I have tried:

```
myConnection.query('INSERT INTO city(id,name) VALUES ($1,$2)', ['nextval("city_sequence_name")','my first city'],callback);
```

But the error rules:

> erro { error: sintaxe de entrada é inválida para integer: "nextval("city_sequence_name")"

Comment: try changing `'nextval("city_sequence_name")'` to`"nextval('city_sequence_name')"`

Comment: I just tried this. The same erro again. Sorry

Comment: Why not simply skip the column then? - `INSERT INTO CITY(NAME) VALUES('my first city');`. This is how one normally lets auto-generated columns generate a new value. Alternatively, one can do `INSERT INTO CITY(ID, NAME) VALUES(DEFAULT, 'my first city');`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I was able to identify the solution to this case:

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO city(id,name) VALUES(nextval('sequence_name'),$1)", ['first city'],callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad practice. Instead, just set the column to `DEFAULT nextval()` or use the `serial` type.

```
# CREATE TABLE city ( id serial PRIMARY KEY, name text );
CREATE TABLE
# \d city
                         Table "public.city"
 Column |  Type   |                     Modifiers                     
--------+---------+---------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer | not null default nextval('city_id_seq'::regclass)
 name   | text    | 
Indexes:
    "city_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

# INSERT INTO city (name) VALUES ('Houston'), ('Austin');
INSERT 0 2
test=# TABLE city;
 id |  name   
----+---------
  1 | Houston
  2 | Austin
(2 rows)
```

Comment: why is it a bad practice? is not good to handle sequence insertion in application code?

Comment: @GaetanoPiazzolla because how often do you want a column that represents a sequence to default to anything but the next value in that sequence? And if it defaults to the next value, why would you want to explicitly write the default in the app code? Moreover, the newer way to do this does not even expose a `nextval()` to the user as it uses `IDENTITY COLUMN`s, which is standardized.

Comment: One thing that maybe you haven't considered: If you do use java and JPA - the library does use a pre- allocation of next val for the sequences, so that it does not need to run a new "nextVal" each time it inserts a new row :)